# How to scrape specific words from table row?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I want to scrape codes only from below table using python

[image]

As in the Image, You can see I just want to **scrape** CPT, CTC, PTC, STC, SPT, HTC, P5TC, P1A, P2A P3A, P1E, P2E, P3E. This codes may change from time to time like the addition of P4E or removal of P1E.

HTML code for above table is:

```html
<table class="list">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>PRODUCT<br>DESCRIPTION</p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p><strong>Time Charter:</strong> CPT, CTC, PTC, STC, SPT, HTC, P5TC<br><strong>Time Charter Trip:</strong> P1A, P2A, P3A,<br>P1E, P2E, P3E</p>
         </td>
         <td><strong>Voyage: </strong>C3E, C4E, C5E, C7E</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>CONTRACT SIZE</p>
            <p></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>1 day</p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>1,000 metric tons</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>MINIMUM TICK</p>
            <p></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>US$ 25</p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>US$ 0.01</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>FINAL SETTLEMENT PRICE</p>
            <p></p>
         </td>
         <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
            <p>The floating price will be the end-of-day price as supplied by the Baltic Exchange.</p>
            <p><br><strong>All products:</strong> Final settlement price will be the mean of the daily Baltic Exchange spot price assessments for every trading day in the expiry month.</p>
            <p><br><strong>Exception for P1A, P2A, P3A:</strong> Final settlement price will be the mean of the last 7 Baltic Exchange spot price assessments in the expiry month.</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>CONTRACT SERIES</p>
         </td>
         <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
            <p><strong><strong>CTC, CPT, PTC, STC, SPT, HTC, P5TC</strong>:</strong> Months, quarters and calendar years out to a maximum of 72 months</p>
            <p><strong>C3E, C4E, C5E, C7E, P1A, P2A, P3A, P1E, P2E, P3E:</strong> Months, quarters and calendar years out to a maximum of 36 months</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>SETTLEMENT</p>
         </td>
         <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
            <p>At 13:00 hours (UK time) on the last business day of each month within the contract series</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see code from below link of website

https://www.eex.com/en/products/global-commodities/freight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your usecase is to scrape all the text:

[image: timecharter]

You you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.eex.com/en/products/global-commodities/freight')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article div:last-child table>tbody>tr td:nth-child(2)>p"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.eex.com/en/products/global-commodities/freight')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[text()='Contract Specifications']//following::table[1]/tbody/tr//following::td[1]/p"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Time Charter: CPT, CTC, PTC, STC, SPT, HTC, P5TC
  Time Charter Trip: P1A, P2A, P3A,
  P1E, P2E, P3E
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update 1

If you want to extract *CPT, CTC, PTC, STC, SPT, HTC, P5TC* and *P1A, P2A, P3A* and *P1E, P2E, P3E* individually, you can use the following solutions:

- Printing *CPT, CTC, PTC, STC, SPT, HTC, P5TC*

  ```
  #element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article div:last-child table>tbody>tr td:nth-child(2)>p")))
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[text()='Contract Specifications']//following::table[1]/tbody/tr//following::td[1]/p")))
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[1].textContent;', element).strip())
  ```
- Printing *P1A, P2A P3A*

  ```
  #element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article div:last-child table>tbody>tr td:nth-child(2)>p")))
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[text()='Contract Specifications']//following::table[1]/tbody/tr//following::td[1]/p")))
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[4].textContent;', element).strip())
  ```
- Printing *P1E, P2E, P3E*

  ```
  //element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article div:last-child table>tbody>tr td:nth-child(2)>p")))
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[text()='Contract Specifications']//following::table[1]/tbody/tr//following::td[1]/p")))
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', element).strip())
  ```

---

### Update 2

To print all the items together:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.eex.com/en/products/global-commodities/freight')
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[text()='Contract Specifications']//following::table[1]/tbody/tr//following::td[1]/p")))
  first = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[1].textContent;', element).strip()
  second = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[4].textContent;', element).strip()
  third = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', element).strip()
  for list in (first,second,third):
      print(list)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  CPT, CTC, PTC, STC, SPT, HTC, P5TC
  P1A, P2A, P3A,
  P1E, P2E, P3E
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I only want codes in the list. Like ['CPT','CTC','PTC','STC','SPT','HTC','P5TC','P1A','P2A','P3A','P1E','P2E','P3E']

Comment: @chintanpatel Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

If variable `txt` contains HTML from your question, then this script extracts all required codes:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
text = soup.select_one('td:contains("Time Charter:")').text
codes = re.findall(r'[A-Z\d]{3}', text)

print(codes)
```

Prints:

```
['CPT', 'CTC', 'PTC', 'STC', 'SPT', 'HTC', 'P5T', 'P1A', 'P2A', 'P3A', 'P1E', 'P2E', 'P3E']
```

---

EDIT: To get codes from all tables, you can use this script:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
all_codes = []
for td in soup.select('td:contains("Time Charter:")'):
    all_codes.extend(re.findall(r'[A-Z\d]{3}', td.text))
print(all_codes)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej. This helped. But can tell me what type of modification is needed if page contains 2 tables. So in this code (text = soup.select_one('td:contains("Time Charter:")').text) will only extract codes from 1st table. Page also contains 2nd table with codes under Time Charter.

Comment: Code output comes in 2 sets. Would be great if you can update code to get this in 1 set. 
Your Output: [ ['CPT', 'CTC', 'PTC', 'STC', 'SPT', 'HTC', 'P5TC', 'P1A', 'P2A', 'P3A', 'P1E', 'P2E', 'P3E'], ['OCPM', 'OCTM', 'OPTM', 'OTSM', 'OPSM', 'OHTM', 'O5PM'] ]
Required Output: ['CPT', 'CTC', 'PTC', 'STC', 'SPT', 'HTC', 'P5TC', 'P1A', 'P2A', 'P3A', 'P1E', 'P2E', 'P3E','OCPM', 'OCTM', 'OPTM', 'OTSM', 'OPSM', 'OHTM', 'O5PM']

Comment: Thank you very much. Excellent answer @Andrej Kesely. This is a complete solution. Really appreciate.